# react-native-webview performance issues when rendering html string

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Am trying to run some html tags am getting from an api but finding it difficult to make the performance as good as native

I have tried using react-native-webview but having serious performance issues with it.

I have also tried react-native-render-html but also had some issues with running some tags like ,  and inline styles same with react-native-htmlview. It renders every other tag correctly with native performance

This is an example of an html string am getting from an api (toRender)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';


const toRender = "<p style='text-decoration: underline'>divide <sup>10<sup>/<sub>2</sub></p>"


class QuestionScreen extends Component{

render{
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <HTML
          html={toRender}
       />
    </View>
)

}
}

export default QuestionScreen
```

Comment: Could please share some code? Just asking for opinion alone may not be helpful, but with some little context and your trials, you might get more than just product recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!